# ggplot: How to retrieve values for axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can you extract the numbers used to label the y and x axes in the ggplot below (respectively `20, 30, 40` and `10 , 15 ,20 ,25, 30, 35`)?

**Plot**

From [r-statistics.co](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html)

[image]

**Reproducible code**

```
# Scatterplot
theme_set(theme_bw())  # pre-set the bw theme.
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy))
g + geom_count(col="tomato3", show.legend=F) +
  labs(subtitle="mpg: city vs highway mileage", 
       y="hwy", 
       x="cty", 
       title="Counts Plot")
```

I've tried looking through the output of `str(g)`, but with lttle success.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Building on CPak's answer, the structure has changed slightly for `ggplot2_3.0.0`. Labels can now be extracted with:

```r
ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.labels
#[1] "20" "30" "40" 
ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.labels
#[1] "10" "15" "20" "25" "30" "35"
```

EDIT:
As of `ggplot2_3.3.0` the labels are found using:

```r
# check package version
utils::packageVersion("ggplot2")

y_labs <- ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y$get_labels()
y_labs[!is.na(y_labs)]
#[1] "20" "30" "40"
x_labs <- ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$get_labels()
x_labs[!is.na(x_labs)]
#[1] "10" "15" "20" "25" "30" "35"
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on the older post - they can be found with

```
ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$y.labels
# "20" "30" "40"
ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.labels
# "10" "15" "20" "25" "30" "35"
```

EDIT: works with `ggplot2_2.2.1` but not `ggplot2 version 3.0.0` - thanks to zx8754 and nilambara for pointing this out

Comment: @CPak `ggplot2 version 3.3.0`: `ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.labels` and
  `ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.labels`