# ggplot2: How to inspect every element of a plot using ggplot_build()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to search the entire output from `ggplot_build()` (or any other function), almost like searching the complete content of every subdirectory of a folder?

---

**The details:**

I was looking for a solution to [Retrieve values for axis labels in ggplot2_3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784640/retrieve-values-for-axis-labels-in-ggplot2-3-0-0), and one of the early answers revealed that, depending on the `ggplot2` version, the correct answer most likely would contain the parts `$layout` and / or `$x.labels` in the output from `ggplot_build(g)`. So I started checking the `ggplot_build()` output each step of the way. One of the steps looks like the output below.

**Snippet 1:**

```
ggplot_build(g)$layout
```

**Output 1:**

```
<ggproto object: Class Layout, gg>
    coord: <ggproto object: Class CoordCartesian, Coord, gg>
        aspect: function
        clip: on

        [...]

    map_position: function
    panel_params: list
    panel_scales_x: list
    panel_scales_y: list
    render: function

        [...]

    ylabel: function
    super:  <ggproto object: Class Layout, gg>
>
```

And deep down there, under `panel params`, `x.labels` can be found along with lots of useful information like this:

**Snippet 2:**

```
ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params
```

**Output 2:**

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`x.range`
[1]  7.7 36.3

[[1]]$x.labels
[1] "10" "15" "20" "25" "30" "35"

[[1]]$x.major
[1] 0.08041958 0.25524476 0.43006993 0.60489510 0.77972028 0.95454545
```

And it can be referenced directly like this:

**Snippet 3:**

```
ggplot_build(g)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.labels
```

**Output 3:**

```
[1] "10" "15" "20" "25" "30" "35"
```

---

**My attempt for a more elegant approach:**

I was certain I could do this with `capture.output()` like you can with `str()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930292/is-it-possible-to-store-str-output-in-a-r-object), but as far as I can tell, you won't find `x.labels` there either. I'm not going to flood the question with that output since it's about 300 lines long.

Thank you for any suggestions!

---

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890388/r-get-element-by-name-from-a-nested-list can give a way to search for names in a list : `rmatch(as.list(ggplot_build(p)$layout), "x.labels")` - needs a bit of tweaking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution for (presumably) for ggplot2 3.0.0 until 3.2.1

This old solution worked for ggplot2 version 3.0.0 and presumably up to 3.2.1, but I have not checked this. A solution for newer versions is below.

This function goes through a nested list structure and finds the paths through that structure that contain a given character string:

```
find_name <- function(obj, name) {
  
  # get all named paths through obj
  find_paths <- function(obj, path) {
    
    if ((!is.list(obj) && is.null(names(obj))) || identical(obj, .GlobalEnv)) {
      return (path)
    } else {
      if (is.null(names(obj))) {
        return(c(path,
                 lapply(seq_along(obj), function(x) find_paths(obj[[x]], paste0(path, "[[", x, "]]")))
              ))
      } else {
        return(c(path,
                 lapply(names(obj), function(x) find_paths(obj[[x]], paste(path, x, sep = "$")))
              ))
      }  
    }
    
  }
  
  # get all the paths through the nested structure
  all_paths <- unlist(find_paths(obj, deparse(substitute(obj))))
  
  # find the requested name
  path_to_name <- grep(paste0("\\$", name, "$"), all_paths, value = TRUE)
  
  return (path_to_name)
}
```

Here is an example of using this function with a `ggplot_built` object:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, col = as.factor(cyl)))
gb <- ggplot_build(p)
find_name(gb, "x.labels")
## [1] "gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.labels"
```

You can also directly get the contents of `x.labels`:

```
eval(parse(text = find_name(gb, "x.labels")))
## [1] "100" "200" "300" "400"
```

A few remarks on how this works:

- The function `find_paths()` goes through the nested structure and returns all "paths" through the structure in a form similar to `"gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.labels"`.
- The nested structure can contain named lists, unnamed lists, named "lists" that have another class (and thus return `FALSE` for `is.list()` and environments. One has to take care of all these situations.
- A particular caveat is that a `ggplot_built` contains a reference to the global environment (`gb$layout$facet_params$plot_env`), which leads to an infinite loop if it is not properly treated.
- The result of `find_paths()` is a nested list again, but the structure can easily be simplified with `unlist()`.
- The last step is to extract those paths that contain the name one is looking for. The regular expression I use ensures that only elements that exactly match the given name are returned. As an example, `find_name(gb, "x")` will not return `"gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.labels"`.

I have tested the function with the `ggplot_built` object from my example and with a nested list. I cannot guarantee that it works for all situations.

### Solution for ggplot2 3.3.0 and newer

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51795017/4303162), the structure of the object returned by `ggplot_build()` has changed in version 3.3.0. The above function then fails because of an infinite loop. The changes that are relevant here are:

- The object contains back references to parent environments called .**enclos_env**`. These are the cause of the infinite loop and must explicitly be caught.
- The object contains functions, which must be explicitly handled. Maybe this was the case already before, but it was not relevant for catching `x.labels` such that I did not notice. According to (again) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51795017/4303162), there is now a function `get_labels()` that returns the labels. So we need to catch those functions as well.

This is an adapted version of the function `find_name()` that works with ggplot2 newer than 3.3.0 (but has only be checked with ggplot2 3.4.4):

```
find_name <- function(obj, name) {

  # get all named paths through obj
  find_paths <- function(obj, path) {
    
    if (is.function(obj)) {
      return(paste0(path, "()"))
    } else if ((!is.list(obj) && is.null(names(obj))) || identical(obj, .GlobalEnv) || grepl("\\.__enclos_env__$", path)) {
      return(path)
    } else {
      if (is.null(names(obj))) {
        return(c(path,
                 lapply(seq_along(obj), function(x) find_paths(obj[[x]], paste0(path, "[[", x, "]]")))
              ))
      } else {
        return(c(path,
                 lapply(names(as.list(obj)), function(x) find_paths(obj[[x]], paste(path, x, sep = "$")))
              ))
      } 
    }
  }

  # get all the paths through the nested structure
  all_paths <- unlist(find_paths(obj, deparse(substitute(obj))))

  # find the requested name
  path_to_name <- grep(paste0("\\$", name, "(\\(\\))$"), all_paths, value = TRUE)

  return (path_to_name)
}
```

The function does not crash, but `x.labels` cannot be found:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, col = as.factor(cyl)))
gb <- ggplot_build(p)
find_name(gb, "x.labels")
## character(0)
```

But it can find all the functions called `get_labels()` (note that you must omit the parenthesis in the name of the function):

```
find_name(gb, "get_labels")
##  [1] "gb$layout$panel_scales_x[[1]]$get_labels()"           "gb$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$get_labels()"          
##  [3] "gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$scale$get_labels()"     "gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$get_labels()"          
##  [5] "gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.sec$scale$get_labels()" "gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.sec$get_labels()"      
##  [7] "gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y$scale$get_labels()"     "gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y$get_labels()"          
##  [9] "gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.sec$scale$get_labels()" "gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.sec$get_labels()"      
## [11] "gb$plot$scales$scales[[1]]$get_labels()"              "gb$plot$scales$scales[[2]]$get_labels()"             
## [13] "gb$plot$scales$scales[[3]]$get_labels()"
```

Comment: I know we're supposed to avoid comments like 'thanks'. But thank you! This looks really cool! Can't wait to try it out!

Comment: When I try to run your code above I get an error after running the `find_name(gb, "x.labels")` line: "Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?". I'm using R 4.3.2 and ggplot2 version 3.4.4.

Comment: @coip Yes, this does no longer work with the current version of ggplot2 because the structure of the object returned by `ggplot_build()` has changed. Also, the field `x.labels` seems to no longer exist (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51795017/4303162)). I managed to fix the code such that it runs again, but will only be able to post it later. But, again, you won't find `x.labels` even with the adapted code.